# Hikari Connecticns not getting closed on hot re-dployment on tomcat in seed application

Tags: tomcat, out-of-memory, redeploy, seedstack

When doing a hot redployment of seed application, it is not able to free the connections from the connection pool. Tomcat throws out of memory exception.

If the deployment is done first time it works fine as there are no existing connections that needs to be released.

Also if we shut down the tomcat instance, it releases the connections properly.

Default Hikari connection pool settings are used and no customization is done.

---

Adding logs:-

Oct 26, 2016 2:46:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deleteRedeployResources
INFO: **Undeploying context** [/test-web-1.0.0]
2016-10-26 14:46:24,156?[0;39m ?[35mContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]?[0;39m ?[36mo.s.s.w.l.Seed ServletContextListener?[0;39m - Stopping Seed Web application
2016-10-26 14:46:24,157?[0;39m ?[35mContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]?[0;39m ?[36mo.s.j.i.JpaPlugin?[0;39m - **Closing entity manager factory for persistence unit test-xxx**
2016-10-26 14:46:24,158?[0;39m ?[35mContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]?[0;39m ?[36mo.s.j.i.JdbcPlugin?[0;39m - **Closing JDBC datasource test_ds**
2016-10-26 14:46:24,159?[0;39m ?[35mContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]?[0;39m ?[36mc.z.h.p.HikariPool?[0;39m - **HikariCP pool HikariPool-0 is shutting down**.
2016-10-26 14:46:24,228?[0;39m ?[35mContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]?[0;39m ?[36mo.s.s.w.l.SeedServletContextListener?[0;39m - **Seed Web application stopped**
?[31m?[0;39mOct 26, 2016 2:46:24 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: **The web application [/test-web-1.0.0] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.**
Oct 26, 2016 2:46:24 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
**SEVERE: The web application [/test-web-1.0.0] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.**
Oct 26, 2016 2:46:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR

INFO: Deploying web application archive F:\Eclipse-New-PSA\Eclipse_DEV\Serveurs\J2EE\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7\webapps\test-web-1.0.0.war

14:46:32,543 |-INFO in LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
14:46:32,543 |-INFO in LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
14:46:32,543 |-INFO in LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/E:/PSA-test/GL_SVN_TEST_ENV/test-conf/test-web/logback.xml]
14:46:32,606 |-INFO in joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
14:46:32,739 |-INFO in LevelChangePropagator@425941ba - Propagating OFF level on Logger[org.reflections] onto the JUL framework
....
....
14:46:32,740 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.TimestampAction - Adding property to the context with key="bySecond" and value="20161026T144632" to the LOCAL steste
14:46:32,746 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [c:/temp/log//TestWeb-20161026T144632.log]
14:46:32,811 |-INFO in joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO

?[34mINFO ?[0;39m ?[33m2016-10-26 14:46:35,062?[0;39m ?[35mlocalhost-startStop-2?[0;39m ?[36mo.s.s.w.l.SeedServletContextListener?[0;39m - Starting Seed Web application
?[31m?[0;39m?[31mWARN ?[0;39m ?[33m2016-10-26 14:46:42,623?[0;39m ?[35mlocalhost-startStop-2?[0;39m ?[36mo.h.e.HibernatePersistence?[0;39m - HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.
jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
2016-10-26 14:46:42,678?[0;39m ?[35mlocalhost-startStop-2?[0;39m ?[36mo.h.j.i.u.LogHelper?[0;39m - HHH000
204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: test-xxx
        ...]
2016-10-26 14:46:42,801?[0;39m ?[35mlocalhost-startStop-2?[0;39m ?[36mo.h.Version?[0;39m - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-10-26 14:46:42,808?[0;39m ?[35mlocalhost-startStop-2?[0;39m ?[36mo.h.c.Environment?[0;39m - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-10-26 14:46:42,810?[0;39m ?[35mlocalhost-startStop-2?[0;39m ?[36mo.h.c.Environment?[0;39m - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-10-26 14:46:43,096?[0;39m ?[35mlocalhost-startStop-2?[0;39m ?[36mo.h.a.c.Version?[0;39m - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-10-26 14:46:43,153?[0;39m ?[35mlocalhost-startStop-2?[0;39m ?[36mc.z.h.HikariDataSource?[0;39m - **HikariCP pool HikariPool-0 is starting.**
2016-10-26 14:46:43,417?[0;39m ?[35mlocalhost-startStop-2?[0;39m ?[36mo.h.d.Dialect?[0;39m - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2016-10-26 14:46:43,908?[0;39m ?[35mlocalhost-startStop-2?[0;39m ?[36mo.h.h.i.a.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory?[0;39m - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
?[31m?[0;39m

### **Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]"**

Comment: Can you post more details about your re-deployment procedure and the stacktrace you get when it errors ? The JDBC add-on closes the datasource  upon kernel stop which happens when the contextDestroyed() method of ServletContextListener is called by the Web server. The out of memory exception could be due to something else like PermGen space.

Comment: I have added logs as requested. We are using jenkins daily build for building and deployment and it just builds and copies the war to the tomcat's webapp folder without restarting the server.

Comment: Your pool was shutting down, but the Tomcat container gave it less than 1 second to do so before complaining.  I suggest you look at Tomcat to see if there is a way to configure a longer shutdown timeout.